# One Window, multiple Views (VB .Net)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I read about MDI-Applications, but that's not what I want.
I would like to have one Window (without child-windows) that can have multiple content-sets.
For example: I want to have a set of lables and textboxes to save information for an object (like a person). This person has several sub-items. I want to have a set of lables and textboxes for these sub-items in my mainform too. But I don't want the lables- and textboxes-set of these two objects to be both visible at the same time.

I hope, you'll understand what I mean (I'm german and I don't really know how to describe my wishes in english). I hope, someone could give me a tip...

Comment: If I understand you, it sounds like you are looking for a TabControl type of thing  With a "Person", "Addresses", "Financial" break-down of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is put your controls in panels and then show or hide the panel appropriately. Here is an example: http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/561eedef-170f-4ccc-98bb-efa4ee97ccdf/?Panel%20Control%20in%20VB.Net

Answer (score 1):

Of course there's the TabControl you can use, but if you don't like that what I would do is build each "view" as a custom control that is the only control on the form.  Then just swap out the entire control as needed.